# Android Studio not found in Flutter Doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I am getting this error when running `flutter doctor`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6yLt.png

```
 X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
 X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your Android Studio installed in `C:\Program`?

Comment: yes its installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use android studio, check the android studio version then you can write "flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" on cmd.

Comment: check on glides your version then check latest version on internet.

Comment: No problem if it helps please tick answer for help others nice dayss

Comment: where can i tick? // okey i did